# How to prove abelian group

Tags: group-theory

I am struggling answering this question for myself:
How can i prove that a Group $G$ is abelian, if $$g\circ g=e \ \forall g \in G $$

A group is abelian if this is true:
$$a\circ b = b\circ a\ \forall a,b \in G$$
But i dont understand how to prove this.

Hope someone can help me out with this!

Comment: $(ab)^2=abab = e \implies aababb = ab  \implies ab=ba. $

Comment: @vnd that is an answer, not a comment

Comment: Simplify $ababba$ in two different ways: one way by replacing $bb$ by $e$ as your first step, another by replacing $abab=(ab)(ab)$ by $e$ as your first step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ commute iff $a \circ b = b \circ a$ iff $a \circ b \circ a^{-1} \circ b ^{-1} = e$.

However $a^{-1} = a$ and $b^{-1} = b$ so then $a \circ b \circ a^{-1} \circ b ^{-1} = a \circ b \circ a \circ b = (a \circ b) \circ (a \circ b) = e$ by hypothesis.

Comment: How does $a=a^{-1}$ and $b=b^{-1}$ without assuming commutativity?

Comment: Nevermind: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3115411/when-is-a-matrix-equal-to-its-own-inverse

Answer (score 2):

Note that $g=g^{-1}$ for any $g$. So, $(ab)^2=abab=e$ and thus $ab=b^{-1}a^{-1} = ba$ for all $a,b \in G$.