# When is a matrix equal to its own inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

When is a matrix equal to its own inverse?

If you have a $2\times2$ matrix and one if the entries is equal to $x$, for what values of $x$ is this matrix equal to its own matrix? And why?

Comment: Do the product $\;A^2=I\;$ and compare entries...

Comment: I'm just curious though, why? How does this relate to the invertible matrix theorem?

Comment: Because $\;A=A^{-1}\iff A^2=I\;$ , multiplying by $\;A\;$ the first equation, and by $\;A^{-1}\;$ the second one.

Comment: $A = A^{-1}$ if and only if $A^2=I$.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, this makes PERFECT SENSE! : )

Comment: @DonAntonio can you make this comment your answer? Because, to me, this answers the question perfectly! I want to accept it.

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site  will help you get the most of your time here. For typesetting your equations, please use MathJax. Here is a great [reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is just to write that
$$
A^2=\left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a^2+bc & (a+d)b\\(a+d)c & d^2+bc\end{matrix}\right)=I.
$$
Since $(a+d)b=(a+d)c=0$, either $a+d=0$ or $b=c=0$.  In the latter case, we must have $a^2=d^2=1$.  In the former case, we must have $a^2+bc=1$... either $a^2=1$ and $bc=0$, or else $a^2\neq 1$ and $bc=1-a^2$.  So
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}\pm 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \pm 1\end{matrix}\right),
$$
or else
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}\pm 1 & b \\ 0 & \mp 1\end{matrix}\right) \text{ or } \left(\begin{matrix}\pm 1 & 0 \\ c & \mp 1\end{matrix}\right),
$$
or
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ (1-a^2)/b & -a\end{matrix}\right) \qquad (a^2\neq 1, b\neq 0).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this step by step explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\;A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\;$ is invertible, then

$$A^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$

Now calculate stuff.

Comment: Compare entries. It will be fun...

Comment: @Gino L just set them equal and solve

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "compare entries". But, honestly, you've been more than helpful. I really appreciate the insight that  =−1⟺2=

Comment: Means $A=A^{-1}$ iff the elements of $A$ are equal to those of $A^{-1}$

Comment: @GinoL. Two matrices are equal if and only if the **all entries** of the two matrices are equal. This means "compare entries".

Comment: 2 years later, I get what he means immediately as I look at this now. Thank you very much for being so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By Cayley-Hamilton we have $A^2-tr(A)A+\det(A)I=0$. Now $A=A^{-1}$ implies $A^2=I$. So we obtain $tr(A)A=(\det(A)+1)I$.  Now the rest is easy.